# Border for Cut-In circular Hole Swift

Tags: ios, swift

[image]I want to add border to the cut in hole (clear in middle and translucent outside). I am using PartialTransparentMaskView for this.

```
https://github.com/heigong/PartialTransparentMaskView
```

The Code looks like this

```
  mapView.clipsToBounds = false

    let frame = mapView.frame

    // Add the mask view
    var array = [CGRect]()
    //to change the circle customize next line
    let rect = CGRectMake(frame.origin.x+20,100, frame.width-40, frame.height-300)

    array.append(rect)

    let maskColor = UIColor(red: 0.9, green: 0.5, blue: 0.9, alpha: 0.5)
    let parentView = mapView.superview
    let pFrame = parentView!.frame
    let maskView = PartialTransparentMaskView(frame: CGRectMake(0, 0, pFrame.width, pFrame.height), backgroundColor: maskColor, transparentRects: nil, transparentCircles:array, targetView: mapView)
    parentView!.insertSubview(maskView, aboveSubview: mapView)
```

How can I add a Red Boundary around the circle?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, I checked the  PartialTransparentMaskView File and I saw the code where the circle is added. I added these lines to draw a boundary:

```
    CGContextSetStrokeColorWithColor(context, UIColor.redColor().CGColor);
            CGContextSetAlpha(context,2);
            CGContextStrokeEllipseInRect(context, holeRectIntersection);
```

The Code portion looks like this:

```
      if let circles = transparentCircles {
        for aRect in circles {

            let holeRectIntersection = aRect

            let context = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();

            if( CGRectIntersectsRect( holeRectIntersection, rect ) )
            {
                CGContextAddEllipseInRect(context, holeRectIntersection);
                CGContextClip(context);
                CGContextClearRect(context, holeRectIntersection);
                CGContextSetFillColorWithColor( context, UIColor.clearColor().CGColor)
                CGContextFillRect( context, holeRectIntersection);
                CGContextSetStrokeColorWithColor(context, UIColor.redColor().CGColor);
                CGContextSetAlpha(context,2);
                CGContextStrokeEllipseInRect(context, holeRectIntersection);
            }


}
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

Add a UIView above maskView, with it's frame squares equal to the radius of the circle, centred at the centre of the circle.

given let circleRadius, let circleCentre be your values

```
...
circleView.borderColor = UIColor.BlackColor()
circleView.borderWidth = 1.0
circleView.backgroundColor = UIColor.clearColor()
circleView.layer.cornerRadius = circleRadius
circleView.frame = CGRectMake(circleCentre.x - circleRadius, circleCentre.y - circleRadius, circleRadius * 2, circleRadius * 2)
parentView!.insertSubview(circleView, aboveSubview: maskView)
```

As example values, that should work if there's nothing funky going on and the view is simply a view on top.

Comment: I don't get it, what is so wrong about this? If you're going to vote down my answer, please at least have the respect to enlighten me why I am wrong.

Comment: It is showing border for the Maskview,which is the whole frame. I want it for the inner circular region.

Comment: I have updated my answer, I had initially thought that the mask view WAS the circle. I'm sorry it was not obvious. Does this help you?

Comment: Will have to check the github link to see what PartialTransparentMaskView is like. It doent have the properties from your code. Thanks for trying!

Answer (score 0):

`maskView` is just a view. It isn't even really a mask; it's just a view with some transparency drawn into it. So draw the red boundary into the view, just like you would draw anything into a view.

Comment: MaskView is the parent. If I add a border to it,it will go around the whole frame not the inner circle.

Comment: I didn't say add a border. I said draw the red boundary, an ellipse.